# What are some examples that show medieval stone construction on top of older foundations?

Tags: middle-ages, architecture, construction, castles, defense

Are there any more blatant examples that show new construction or repairs on older construction? Buildings like castles or walls With visible differences between the two construction eras? For example the city walls of [London](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Site_of_St_Alphage%2C_London_Wall_-_geograph.org.uk_-_643181.jpg), showing the Roman and medieval constructs.

Comment: Including existing structures into new buildings was really common. See e.g. [Chartres Cathedral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartres_Cathedral) in France or the [Marktkirche in Halle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marktkirche_Unser_Lieben_Frauen), Germany. Both have (parts of) their towers from older churches. You might want to specify what exactly you mean by "older" and also by "foundations".

Comment: Also, a number of users on this site usually want you to explain why you could not come up with an answer yourself, because this can also help to clarify the question, the level of required detail etc.

Comment: For a start and because you mentioned Roman city walls, you might look into some of the examples at [the relevant wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Roman_defensive_walls), even though it does not look particularly comprehensive (e.g. it is missing the [city walls of Le Mans, France](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enceinte_gallo-romaine_du_Mans)). But the topic is really much wider than that, even if one limits oneself to medieval buildings on _ancient_ foundations, and only to defensive structures.

Comment: The [Porta Nigra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porta_Nigra) in Trier is a Roman city gate from the 2nd century AD. In the 11th century it was converted into two churches, one on the lower floor, one on the upper floor. For this an apse was added to the east tower, and a spire was added to the west tower. The churches existed until Napoleonic times. Does that fall under your definition of "repairs on older construction"?

Comment: Questions that ask for examples make it difficult to provide an [authoritative answer](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4274/1401).

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of examples of Roman buildings and structures reused, rebuild, repurposed or build over in Medieval and later times.

One example: [Casa de l'Ardiaca in Barcelona](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Casa_de_l%27Ardiaca), a medieval and later renaissance palace built on the Roman wall and reused, reformed and repurposed until our century.

[image: Casa de l'Ardiaca]
([image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Casa_de_l%27Ardiaca_de_festa_major_P1160395.JPG))

Another example where medieval rebuilding appears clearer: [Chapel of Santa Àgata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapel_of_Santa_%C3%80gata), also in Barcelona, a Gothic chapel build on top of the Roman wall - by then no longer needed as a city wall because Barcelona had a larger wall.

[image: Chapel of Santa Àgata on top of the Roman wall]
([Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Muralla_romana_1.jpg))

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Clemente_al_Laterano

Saint Clemente Basilica in Rome, a three-tiered complex of buildings:

1. the present basilica built just before the year 1100 during the height of the Middle Ages - although the decoration is newer than that;
2. beneath the present basilica is a 4th-century basilica that had been converted out of the home of a Roman nobleman, part of which had in the 1st century briefly served as an early church, and the basement of which had in the 2nd century briefly served as a mithraeum;
3. the home of the Roman nobleman had been built on the foundations of republican era villa and warehouse that had been destroyed in the Fire of 64

I have visited 1) and 2). In (2), you can see the nave (although, as the roof is the floor of the next level, it has a low height) the tombs of Saints Cyril and Methodius, the Apostles of the Slavs - orthodox people also go there to visit them - and, in a lower level, the mithraeum, where the pagans would sacrifice animals, there are benches, altar, and channels where the blood would flow.

The different levels are obviously built with different architectural styles and materials.

some pics:
https://lavieboheme2010.blogspot.com/2013/09/the-four-worlds-of-basilica-san-clemente.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Colchester Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colchester_Castle), built on the base of the temple of Claudius, destroyed at the time of Boadicea. You can see an oyster shell from Roman times in the vaulted basement of the castle; it is embedded in the concrete.